# How to randomly draw an element without having duplicates values in a loop

Tags: r

UPDATED QUESTION :

In a loop, I would like to choose a color for each occurrence without ever having the same twice

```
myvec <- c("green","blue","red","orange","dark","white")

for (i in (1:6)) {
    
    mycolor <- sample(myvec,1,replace=F)
    
    print(mycolor)
    
}

# Return
[1] "dark"
[1] "blue"
[1] "red"
[1] "red"
[1] "blue"
[1] "blue"
```

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to draw your sample *outside* the loop and then access the required element inside the loop.

Comment: Given that you have 6 colors, and 10 occurrences, don't you have to repeat a colour at least once in order to have a color for all 10 occurrences? The alternative is to have less occurrences?

Comment: I  am confused from what you write. You iterate from 1 to 10, myvec contains 6 elements, but you do not want to have same color twice?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I updated my question with 6 occurences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
myvec <- c("green","blue","red","orange","dark","white")

for (i in (1:6)) {
    
    mycolor <- sample(myvec,1,replace=F)
    
    print(mycolor)
    myvec <- setdiff(myvec, mycolor)
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From @Limey's comment:
Take the sample before the loop:

```
myvec <- c("green","blue","red","orange","dark","white")

mycolor <- sample(myvec, replace=F)

for (i in (1:6)) {    
  print(mycolor[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scramble your color vector, so you can just use the colors in the scrambled order, later:

```
myvec <- c("green","blue","red","orange","dark","white")
scram <- rnorm(length(myvec),0,1)
myvec = myvec[order(scram)] ## Now, it's randomly sorted

for (i in (1:6)) {
    mycolor <- myvec[i]
    print(mycolor)  
}
```

Comment: you could also just use `myvec <- sample(myvec)`

Comment: Yes, you could use sample(). But you'd lose the order for further reference. I don't like that. But that's personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

What about a `while` loop?

```
myvec <- c("green","blue","red","orange","dark","white")
my_colors = c()
while (length(my_colors) < 6) {
        
        mycolor <- sample(myvec,1,replace=F)
        
        if (!mycolor %in% my_colors) {
                my_colors = c(my_colors, mycolor)
                print(mycolor)
        } else {
                next
        }
        
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "blue"
[1] "white"
[1] "orange"
[1] "green"
[1] "red"
[1] "dark"
```

`my_colors` will contain your colors:

```
my_colors

[1] "blue"   "dark"   "green"  "white"  "red"    "orange"
```